# Shift+Alt key combination blocks input in terminal (Ubuntu 10.04)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, keyboard, terminal, shortcuts

I have a weird problem with polish accents on Ubuntu 10.04 in terminal (no X server).
When I try to type big letter Ł, it works when it is typed by pressing right <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>. BUT when you press <kbd>Shift</kbd> first (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> as opposed to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>) - it doesn't work.

Any ideas why?

Update: I have narrowed the problem to just pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>. It's enough to block further typing - for example when I type "zxc", screen shows: `^[z^[x^[c`.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer to this problem. It turns out that, when I issue `loadkeys pl` command to load polish keymap, it somehow maps Shift+Alt combination to something. To prevent this behaviour, I had to do:

```
loadkeys pl
dumpkeys > pl.kmap
```

Then, I've edited the pl.kmap file, removing all entries below `keycode 100 = AltGr` line.
Finally, I've added

```
loadkeys ./pl.kmap
```

To my `.profile` file, and it worked! Now I can input any key combination without any trouble.